# nginx записать файла если клиент оборвал соединение

Tags: nginx

Проблема происходит в следующей схеме:

```
-> Клиент устанавливает соединение
<- Сервер принимает соединение
-> Клиент начинает писать файл
<- nginx его читает
-> клиент падает, закрывает соединение... еще 100500 причин, почему клиент не закрыл соединение правильно
<- nginx возвразщает 400, файл потерян
```

Как заставить nginx все же записать этот файл?

Comment: Отключить буферизацию запросов и сразу читать файл тем скриптом, который будет его записывать

Comment: Возможно `proxy_request_buffering off` но не проверял